# Discovered @Override but still get [I@232204a1 print output

Tags: java, overriding

Edit #2: Solved. I just have to call directly from the array and not call the entire Map. This is pretty cool, but unsettling because it means there's code I can't check line by line.

Still:
Where can I read more about the inner workings of statements? Do I just need to view the actual files within my java directory and the html javadocs?

I've been programming in python for about 3 months and just picked up Java a week ago for a university class. I've been going beyond the call of duty, but have finally reached a problem my Google skills cannot fix.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

class Complex {
    private double re;

    public Complex(double re) {
        this.re = re;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(re + "N");
    }
}

public class New {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ~~100 lines of functioning code~~
            Map<Complex, int[]> dict = new HashMap<>();
            for (int x = 0; x <= tokens.length - 1; x++) {
                Complex str = new Complex(x);
                int[] anArray = new int[3];

                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                anArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[x].split("/")[i]);                                                                     
                }
                dict.put(str, anArray);
                System.out.print("\n"+dict.get(str)+"\n\n");
            }
```

However, this outputs "[I@75b84c92" and "[I@232204a1" for x values of 1 and 2 (similar for 3), respectively. I understand that these are object codes. However, If I hard code the loop, I go no more errors.

```
                if(tokens.length == 1) {
                    String[] date1 = tokens[0].split("/");
                    int foo1 = Integer.parseInt(date1[0]);
                    int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(date1[1]);
                    int foo3 = Integer.parseInt(date1[2]);
                } else if (tokens.length == 2) {
                    String[] date1 = tokens[0].split("/");
                    int foo1 = Integer.parseInt(date1[0]);
                    int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(date1[1]);
                    int foo3 = Integer.parseInt(date1[2]);
                    String[] date2 = tokens[1].split("/");
                    int doo1 = Integer.parseInt(date2[0]);
                    int doo2 = Integer.parseInt(date2[1]);
                    int doo3 = Integer.parseInt(date2[2]);
                } else if (tokens.length == 3) {
                    ~~etc. etc. etc. etc.~~
```

Editing due to recent reply: It appears that my error is not coming from my complex object, but when calling int[] via another hidden .toString during my print statement.

Comment: dear user either I am too tired or your question is not either clear or confusing to me? :)

Comment: what you mean by 'everything works perfectly later', do you have problem with toString of Complex?

Comment: dict.get(str) --> will give you an int[] array, when toString() is invoked on an array, it will just print out its hashcode, and thats what you are getting. If you want the values in it, iterate the int[] that you get on making dict.get(str).

Comment: Iterating worked! I guess that I was so worked up that I couldn't check this part of myy code, I forgot to just write code around the problem and see if it worked. Thank you BatScream and Adi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `System.out.print("\n"+dict.get(str)+"\n\n");`, you are actually calling toString of int[], not of your Complex object. This is expected output for array toString.